# Different span and input padding

Tags: html, css

I would like to know why the span and input have different padding even if I set it the same. It behaves the same in Firefox and Chrome. Which CSS rule affects this?

```css
span, input {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 16pt;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span>Some text</span>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`line-height` doesn't affect span because, by default, it is "inline"  and input is inline-block. So if you set for span `display: inline-block` it should work

```css
span, input {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 16pt;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block; /* << here */
}
```

```html
<span>Some text</span>
<input type="text">
```